# Storing arrays in Set and avoiding duplicates

Tags: java, arrays, generics, hash, set

```
HashSet<String[]> boog = new HashSet<String[]>();
boog.add(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"});
boog.add(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"});
boog.add(new String[]{"a", "b", "d"});
```

results in

```
[a, b, c]
[a, b, d]
[a, b, c]
```

where `[a,b,c]` is repeated, so the hash function is not working as expected. How would I go about overriding the Hash method for String arrays. Or for that matter, a generic array? Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You might also be interested in Eric Lippert's article [Arrays Considered Somewhat Harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx), where he talks about some of the reasons why the array abstraction causes more problems than it solves.  His comments specifically deal with .NET, but many of the same points apply to the Java platform.

Comment: I think adding Arrays.toString() to HashSet will work for you. And for retreiving arrays use string.split()

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can't. arrays use the default identity-based Object.hashCode() implementation and there's no way you can override that. Don't use Arrays as keys in a HashMap / HashSet!

Use a Set of Lists instead.

Answer (score 39):

The "better way" is to use collections.  Use a `List` instead of a `String[]`:

```
// TreeSet and other comparison based sets will not work as ArrayList does not implement Comparable
Set<List<String>> boog = new HashSet<>();
boog.add(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
boog.add(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
boog.add(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "d"));

System.out.println(boog.size()); // 2
```

### Edit

If you absolutely needed to use arrays as keys, you could build a transparent wrapper around each key and put that in the map.  Some libraries help you with that.  For example, here's how you could do a `Set<String[]>` using [Trove](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/):

```
Set<String[]> boog = new TCustomHashSet<String[]>(new ArrayHashingStrategy());

boog.add(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"});
boog.add(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"});
boog.add(new String[]{"a", "b", "d"});

System.out.println(boog.size()); // 2

//...
public class ArrayHashingStrategy extends HashingStrategy<Object[]> {

   public int computeHashCode(Object[] array) {
      return Arrays.hashCode(array);
   }

   public boolean equals(Object[] arr1, Object[] arr2) {
      return Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2);
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 for spelling out `Set<List<String>>` and for using `Arrays.asList()`, which is almost certainly what the OP wants.

Comment: Does the order of elements in the List (inside the set) matters to determine duplication? I mean is 
```boog.add(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"});

boog.add(new String[]{"b", "a", "c"});

boog.add(new String[]{"a", "b", "d"});```

?

Comment: @ApJo: Yes, order would matter as `Arrays.hashCode` and `Arrays.equals` are both sensitive to order.  If order didn't matter you could use another data type for keys like a `Set<Set<String>>`.  Bear in mind that using `List` instead of an array would be the preferred approach, and the Trove example is 11 years old and that project is no longer maintained.

Comment: yep, the order does matter, thanks @MarkPeters

Answer (score 5):

`hashCode()` of arrays uses the default implementation, which doesn't take into account the elements, and you can't change that.

You can use a `List` instead, with a `hashCode()` calculated based on the hashcodes of its elements. `ArrayList` (as most implementations) uses such function.

---

Alternatively (but less preferable, unless you are forced somehow to use arrays), you can use a 'special' `HashSet` where instead of invoking `key.hashCode()` invoke `Arrays.hashCode(array)`. To implement that extend `HashMap` and then use `Collections.newSetFromMap(map)`

Comment: The problem with the latter approach is that HashSet internally uses HashMap, so you will have to provide a replacement for that as well. And the HashMap is in a private field, so you'll have to do it with Reflection. Messy.

Comment: true, then extend HashMap and use `Collections.newSetFromMap(..)`

Comment: The suggestion to extend `HashMap` doesn't work. `HashMap` has a method `hash(key)` which is used by many other methods. We can't override `hash(key)` (because it's package-private in older JDK versions and static in newer versions), and we also can't override some of the methods calling `hash(key)` (because they are package-private). `HashMap` isn't designed for extension.

Comment: 'HashMap' source code in OpenJDK: [Version that was current when the answer was written](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/b6bee3c9e9a85d79607e7c3c6bc51d6f7f23ffe7/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java) / [Current version](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can. You can use `TreeSet` with provided `Comparator`.
In your case it will be something like:

```
Set<String[]> boog = new TreeSet<>((o1, o2) -> {
    for (int i = 0; i < o1.length; i++){
        int cmp = o1[i].compareTo(o2[i]);
        if (cmp != 0) {
            return cmp;
        }
    }
    return o1.length - o2.length;
});
```

Under the hood it will looks like alphabetic sorted tree.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually using the default `hashCode` method returning different values for all your different arrays!

The best way to solve this is either to use a `Collection` (such as a `List` or a `Set`) or to define your own wrapper class such as:

```
public class StringArray {
    public String[] stringArray;

    [...] // constructors and methods

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        for(String string : stringArray){
            result = prime * result + ((string == null) ? 0 : string.hashCode());
        }
    }
}
```

This class actually uses pretty much the same `hashCode` method as the one for the `List`.

You now handle:

```
HashSet<StringArray> boog = new HashSet<StringArray>();
```

Comment: Just a note that `Arrays.asList` provides a perfectly usable wrapper for you already.

Comment: Perfectly true. It should even be preferred. Yet I was just offering an alternative way, or more exactly I showed how he wanted it to work :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TreeSet`.

`TreeSet` uses `Comparable.compareTo()` or `Comparator.compare()` instead of `hashCode()` and `equals()` to compare elements. It can be specified in the constructor.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String[]> boog = new TreeSet<>(Arrays::compare);
    boog.add(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"});
    boog.add(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"});
    boog.add(new String[]{"a", "b", "d"});
    for (String[] e : boog)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(e));
}
```

output:

```
[a, b, c]
[a, b, d]
```

`Arrays::compare` is a `Comparator` that compares arrays in lexicographical order.