# Java Set doesn't store a similar list with same elements but it stores a duplicate for arrays

Tags: java, arrays, list, set

How does set compare objects in java?

I was reading java documentation for equals method for arrays and list and from the documentation it looks similar. Is there a better way to differentiate.

This post just recommends to use list but I wanted to understand how do I know for other data structures?
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488098/storing-arrays-in-set-and-avoiding-duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com)

For example:

```
   int[] arr1 = new int[] {1, 2};
   int[] arr2 = new int[] {1, 2};
   if (arr1 == arr2) {
      // doesn't get printed
      System.out.println("hello");
   }
   Set<int[]> set1 = new HashSet<>();
   set1.add(arr1);
   set1.add(arr2);
   System.out.println(set1.size());
   // Prints 2
```

```
    Set<List<Integer>> set = new HashSet<>();
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
    set.add(list1);
    set.add(list2);
    if (list1 == list2) {
    // doesn't get printed
      System.out.println("hello");
    }
    System.out.println(set);
    System.out.println(set.size());
    // Prints
    // [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
    // 1
```

Comment: Where did you read equals documentation for arrays?  In any event, what matters is `.equals`, not `==`.

Comment: This might be a partial duplicate of [What is the difference between == and equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7520432/6395627).

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting. When drafting your Question, note how similar existing questions do not address your issue.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... How does set compare objects in java? ..."*

There are different implementations of the *[Set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html)* interface.

In your particular example, you're using the *[HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html)*, which utilizes a *[Map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html)*, or more accurately, a *[HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html)*.
Of which, in turn, generates a *"[hash-code](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode())"* value of the supplied *key*, upon entry.
Meaning, no two *keys* may have the same *hash-code*.

Here is the source code, for *[HashMap#put](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,V))*.
*[GitHub – OpenJDK – HashMap.java – put(K, V)](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L617)*.

```java
/**
 * Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map.
 * If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old
 * value is replaced.
 *
 * @param key key with which the specified value is to be associated
 * @param value value to be associated with the specified key
 * @return the previous value associated with {@code key}, or
 *         {@code null} if there was no mapping for {@code key}.
 *         (A {@code null} return can also indicate that the map
 *         previously associated {@code null} with {@code key}.)
 */
public V put(K key, V value) {
    return putVal(hash(key), key, value, false, true);
}
```

And, here is *HashMap#putVal*.
*[GitHub – OpenJDK – HashMap.java – putVal(int, K, V, boolean, boolean)](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L631)*.

It appears to be the typical *Set* abstraction; allowing only unique values.
Here is a relevant *Wikipedia* article.
*[Wikipedia – Set (abstract data type)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type))*.

```java
/**
 * Implements Map.put and related methods.
 *
 * @param hash hash for key
 * @param key the key
 * @param value the value to put
 * @param onlyIfAbsent if true, don't change existing value
 * @param evict if false, the table is in creation mode.
 * @return previous value, or null if none
 */
final V putVal(int hash, K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent,
               boolean evict) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> p; int n, i;
    if ((tab = table) == null || (n = tab.length) == 0)
        n = (tab = resize()).length;
    if ((p = tab[i = (n - 1) & hash]) == null)
        tab[i] = newNode(hash, key, value, null);
    else {
        Node<K,V> e; K k;
        if (p.hash == hash &&
            ((k = p.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            e = p;
        else if (p instanceof TreeNode)
            e = ((TreeNode<K,V>)p).putTreeVal(this, tab, hash, key, value);
        else {
            for (int binCount = 0; ; ++binCount) {
                if ((e = p.next) == null) {
                    p.next = newNode(hash, key, value, null);
                    if (binCount >= TREEIFY_THRESHOLD - 1) // -1 for 1st
                        treeifyBin(tab, hash);
                    break;
                }
                if (e.hash == hash &&
                    ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                    break;
                p = e;
            }
        }
        if (e != null) { // existing mapping for key
            V oldValue = e.value;
            if (!onlyIfAbsent || oldValue == null)
                e.value = value;
            afterNodeAccess(e);
            return oldValue;
        }
    }
    ++modCount;
    if (++size > threshold)
        resize();
    afterNodeInsertion(evict);
    return null;
}
```

> *"... This post just recommends to use list but I wanted to understand how do I know for other data structures? ..."*

Here is a *Wikipedia* article, listing the different types of *data structures*.
*[Wikipedia – List of data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures)*.

Comment: _Meaning, no two keys may have the same hash-code_: sorry but this is nonsense. The Strings "aa" and "bB" have the same hashcode (3104) but I can easily add both of them to a `HashSet`.

Comment: @ThomasKläger, _putVal(hash(key), key, value, false, true)_.

Comment: @ThomasKläger, and, why don't you just write an answer?

Comment: The condition in `putVal()` is `p.hash == hash &&  ((k = p.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k)))`  which means that not only the hash values must match, it must also be true that the keys are either the same object (`p.key == key`) or if key is not null `key.equals(k)`

Comment: @ThomasKläger, ok, what should I adjust?

Comment: I would write something like "no two equal keys (as defined by the `equals(Object)` method) may be added. Note that objects that are equal according to `equals(Object)` must have the same `hashCode()`".

Comment: @ThomasKläger, cool thanks, dude.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, double equals (==) on objects compares pointer equality.  So only two pointers to the same object instance will return true.

```
int[] arr1 = new int[] { 1, 2 };
int[] arr2 = new int[] { 1, 2 };
int[] arr3 = arr2;
System.out.println(arr1 == arr2); // false
System.out.println(arr3 == arr2); // true
```

By default `Object.equals()` does the same thing.  You can override it to do something sensible for a class you define.  Obviously `java.util.ArrayList` does this.

A set is supposed to ensure that no two members are the same according to `Object.equals()`.  According to the documentation on `java.util.Set`: ["More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2)"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html)  However, this doesn't work the way you might expect.

For example, a `java.util.HashSet` doesn't call `Object.equals()` on its members when they're added unless the `Object.hashCode()` method returns the same value.  Here's an example of how you would create a custom class that avoids duplicating entries using `HashSet`:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class CustomArray {
    protected int[] _a;
    public CustomArray(int[] a) { _a = a; }
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = _a.length;
        for (int ii = 0; ii < _a.length; ++ii)
            result += ((Integer)_a[ii]).hashCode();
        return result;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if ((o != null) && (o instanceof CustomArray) &&
            (((CustomArray)o)._a.length == _a.length)) {
           boolean result = true;
           for (int ii = 0; ii < _a.length; ++ii)
               if (((CustomArray)o)._a[ii] != _a[ii])
                   result = false;
        } else result = false;
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<CustomArray> s = new HashSet<>();
        s.add(new CustomArray(new int[] {1, 2}));
        s.add(new CustomArray(new int[] {1, 2}));
        System.out.println(s.size());  // prints "1"
    }
}
```

In practice you might want to implement `hashCode()` differently to make collisions less likely (a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) might work).  I also recommend making your custom class immutable if possible, since changing the contents of a set member may invalidate the set assumption with surprising results.